# ¿Como ejecutar 2 o mas procedimientos almacenados con mysqli en php?

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo 2 procedimientos almacenados en el mismo archivo, la conexión se realiza de manera correcta ya que si borro cualquiera de los 2 procedimientos el otro si muestra información pero si dejo ambos solo se ejecuta el primero.

Tengo el archivo `conectar.php` con el sig código:

```
class Clase_Conecta{
     var $_Server = 'localhost';
     var $_User = 'root';
     var $_Password = '';
     var $_Bd = 'bd1';

     function Fn_getConnect(){
        if (!($conexion = new mysqli($this -> _Server, $this -> _User, $this -> _Password, $this -> _Bd))){
           echo "Error Conectando la base de Datos";
           exit();
        }else{
          echo "conexion exitosa";
        }
        return $conexion;
     }
  }
```

Y mi archivo `principal.php` con lo sig:

```
include ("conectar.php");
$Fn = new Clase_Conecta();
$Cn = $Fn -> Fn_getConnect();

$sql1 = "call sp1()";
$r = query($sql1);

while ($rP = $r -> fetch_array()){
            //Imprime tabla
       }

//Hasta aquí funciona bien pero si quiero ejecutar otro procedimiento almacenado no lo hace
//solo ejecuta el de arriba (el primero)

$sql2 = "call sp2()";
$r2 = query($sql2);

 while ($rP2 = $r2 -> fetch_array()){
            //Imprime tabla
     }
```

Me imagino que estoy comprendiendo mal los conceptos pero ya leí e investigue y no me queda del todo claro, por favor si alguien es tan amable de orientarme de que estoy haciendo mal o que estoy omitiendo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verás, no te funciona porque te falta el `;` en el código sql.

Es un error en la sintaxis sql.

El código te debe quedar así:

```
include ("conectar.php");
$Fn = new Clase_Conecta();
$Cn = $Fn -> Fn_getConnect();

$sql1 = "call sp1();";
$r = query($sql1);

while ($rP = $r -> fetch_array()){
            //Imprime tabla
       }
$r->close();
$Cn->next_result();
//Hasta aquí funciona bien pero si quiero ejecutar otro procedimiento almacenado no lo hace
//solo ejecuta el de arriba (el primero)

$sql2 = "call sp2();";
$r2 = query($sql2);

 while ($rP2 = $r2 -> fetch_array()){
            //Imprime tabla
     }
 $r2->close();
 $Cn->next_result();
```

[php](/questions/tagged/php)[mysqli](/questions/tagged/mysqli)

Comment: Gracias por responder, fíjate que ya modifique lo del ; y tampoco así funciona, hace lo mismo, si comento el bloque de código donde ejecuto el 2do sp me ejecuta el 1ro y si borro el bloque de código del 1er sp me ejecuta el 2do sp, pero si dejo ambos solo ejecuta el 1ro.

Comment: Devuelve algún parámetro de salida?

Comment: Los procedimientos ninguno, solamente me muestra 4 filas el 1ro y 7 filas el 2do.

Comment: He modificado la llamada

Comment: Si lo acabo de ver y me disculpo por haberlo escrito mal pero en mi código original si tengo lo que acabas de agregar, osea lo tengo igual que tu ultima actualización y me sigue sucediendo lo mismo :/

Comment: Ya modifique mi código y ahora no me muestra ninguno de los 2 sp, espera no había notado que modificaste algo mas, deja vuelvo a modificar

Comment: $Cn es el objeto que tiene la conexion? Has puesto esto ultimo? `$r2->close();
 $Cn->next_result();`

Comment: Espera es que no vi que agregaste algo mas, ahorita modifico mi código

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50964/discussion-between-sakulino-and-el-condor).